# grunt usemin php include css

Tags: javascript, php, include, gruntjs

I'm trying to solve a problem with my grunt task, in my index.php i use a php include for my head tag :

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>yo</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- build:css(.tmp) css/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <script src="js/modernizr/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

But when I run my grunt task the usemin throws cssmin failed,

```
grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'clean:dist',
    /*'includes',*/
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
]);
```

So I think when the usemin parse the index.php file, the include has not been resolved, If I put the head tag content in directly in my file, it works... I tried to use grunt-include, but in my dev mode the syntax is wrong.. help please ^^

Comment: Usemin works with HTML only.

Comment: ok... so any advice to make include ?

Answer (score 0):

Use grunt-curl as your first task to retrieve the rendered HTML from your PHP pages, store in a folder and then run all grunt tasks on the rendered HTML instead :)
https://github.com/twolfson/grunt-curl